# device specific error (Oneplus HD1901) getting Error : Process name is com.skyone.skycandle, not key_process in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, gradle, android-manifest

I am working on an application, an application running well except oneplus HD1901 device, application crash & getting an error is "Process name is com.skyone.skycandle, not key_process"

even added default package name in process like this >  "android:process = "com.skyone.skycandle" in manifest file

and tried many other solutions but did not get any success.

[image]

Comment: I am getting a similar error on OnePlus 11 5G, the app is getting crashed. I have JNI code that process network packets. On other devices, it seems to work fine.